# Python list range access as a ring buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python list and would like to build the ranged loop list. It looks like a ring buffer. So if I have a list:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
```

I would like to get:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[2], [3], [4], [0]]
[[3], [4], [0], [1]]
[[4], [0], [1], [2]]
```

I could do it by myself. But is there any better or smarter ways in Python 3?

The code I have tried:

```
N = 5
d_list = [[_] for _ in range(N)]
for i in range(N):
    b1 = i
    e1 = i + N - 1
    b2, e2 = 0, 0
    if e1 >= N:
        e2 = e1 - N
    print(d_list[b1:e1] + d_list[b2:e2])
```

Answer (score 2):

what about using a `collections.deque` and `rotate` ?

```
import collections

N = 5

d = collections.deque(range(N))
for _ in range(N):
    print(d)
    d.rotate(1)
```

result:

```
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
deque([4, 0, 1, 2, 3])
deque([3, 4, 0, 1, 2])
deque([2, 3, 4, 0, 1])
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 0])
```

`rotate` just changes the start of the list, no data is copied/moved, so it's very fast.

note:

- you can convert into `list` if needed
- my example is using integers, not lists containing one sole integer. This can be easily adapted if necessary.

Comment: OP: You can do `collections.deque([i] for i in range(N))` if you want to rotate a list of lists

Answer (score 0):

This Python function rotates anything slice-able as you desire:

```
def rotate(l, y=1):
   if len(l) == 0:
      return l
   y = -y % len(l)     # flip rotation direction
   return l[y:] + l[:y]

>>> rotate([1,2,3,4,5],2)
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> rotate([1,2,3,4,5],-22)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
>>> rotate('abcdefg',3)
'efgabcd'
>>> for i in range(N):
...    print(d_list)
...    d_list=rotate(d_list)
... 
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[4], [0], [1], [2], [3]]
[[3], [4], [0], [1], [2]]
[[2], [3], [4], [0], [1]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [0]]
```

Note that in Python 3, `range` is not sliceable. You first would need to create a list with `list(range(...))`

The sign convention is the same as `deque.rotate`